# store word content in variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I copy the entire content (approx 2 pages) of a Word document in VBA and store in a variable?

I keep trying several things, none of which works:

```
Dim mainData As String
ThisDocument.Activate
ActiveDocument.WholeStory 'error on this line
mainData = Selection.Text
```

With 'record macro' I can simulate selecting a piece or the entire text, but I can't simulate storing that into a variable.

The above code throws

> 'This command is not available because no document is open',

but hadn't I first activated this (the current) document, and then selected it (`ActiveDocument.WholeStory`)? 
Why doesn't this work?

**Later edit:** I managed to do the selection like this:

```
Dim sText As String
Application.Selection.ClearFormatting
Application.Selection.WholeStory
sText = Application.Selection.Text
MsgBox sText
```

but the problem is I can't store the entire text (2 pages) in a variable. Part of it is truncated. Would you know how to store word by word (I only need a word at a time anyway)?

**Later edit.** I applied `strReverse` on the text to find out the text is actually stored entirely in the variable, just not fully displayed in the message box.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711120/how-to-loop-through-each-word-in-a-word-document-vba-macro

Comment: Solved, thank you very much Slai and Cindy. I can't upvote your comments. Very useful, both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `ThisDocument` in code, unless you specifically want to address the file in which the code is stored and running. `ThisDocument` is the "code name" of that file.

Instead, use `ActiveDocument` to mean the document currently active in the Word window.

An addition, if you want the Selection in the currently active document, there's no reason to *activate* it - it's already active.

So to get the entire document content in a string

```
Dim mainData As String
mainData = ActiveDocument.Content.Text
```

where `Content` returns the entire main body's text as a Range object.

Note: The MsgBox has an upper character limit. If you're working with long text strings and want to see what they hold the following has more (but not "infinite") capacity:

```
Debug.Print mainData
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
Dim mainData As String
mainData = ActiveDocument.Range.Text
```