# Section Header Range.Text Returning Empty String Instead of Actual Text

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I have a PDF file that I am trying to parse text out of. I opened the file using Microsoft Word, and text I need is in the header. On the first page, the header is justified left with a center tab that has the text (plain English name document title instead of the complicated reference name) that I am trying to grab. There is a right tab that has a page number control that I don't care about.

When I try to run the following:

```
Debug.Print ThisDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Exists
```

it gives me `True`, so I know the header exists. However, when I try to run

```
Debug.Print ThisDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
```

it gives me nothing but an empty string, which I can further confirm by wrapping it in a `Len(…)` command which gives me `1`. How can I get the text out of the header?

Of note, I tried using some Adobe SDK functions which would have been easier, but I do not have the professional Acrobat suite so I do not have access to those tools. Hence the MS Word workaround.

Comment: Most likely your pdf is not appropriately tagged and MS Word cannot recognize as headers what you consider to be header material.

Comment: `ThisDocument` refers exclusively to the file in which the macro is contained. That's unlikely to be the PDF file, which you want to address. Use `ActiveDocument` instead and see if that helps. If not, please tell us which VERSION of Word you're using.

Comment: @CindyMeister, that did it, thank you! If you put that into an official answer I'll mark it as accepted. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store word content in variable vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581503/store-word-content-in-variable-vba)

Comment: I'd like to take some credit :-), but this is a common problem so I've marked it as a "duplicate" where there's already a fuller explanation about the two objects.

Comment: Take the credit, you have the accepted answer at that link anyway ;)